# Uploading multiple images from Share Extension

Tags: ios

I currently have a share extension set up that will upload an image selected from the Photo app to a server.  This works fine using the code below.

```
 int fileNum=10;

NSItemProvider *attachment = inputItem.attachments[0];
if ([attachment hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage])
{
    [attachment loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(id item,NSError *error)
     {
         if (item)
         {
             NSLog (@"image %@",item);
             //upload image here
             NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:item];
             activityRecord.activityType=@"Images";
             AppRecord *appRecord=[[AppRecord alloc] init];
             appRecord.fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"activity_%@%i(%i).jpg",activityRecord.supplierID,activityRecord.activityID,fileNum];
             appRecord.fileBytes=data;
             [fileRecords addObject:appRecord];
             activityRecord.activityFiles=fileRecords;
             [[Settings getInstance] uploadActivityRecord:activityRecord withDelegate:self];
             [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:nil];
         }
     }];
}
```

I had a previous problem where the `loadItemForTypeIdentifier` method wasn't being called, and it was resolved by calling `completeRequestReturningItems` within the completion block.
The problem I have now is that if I want to upload multiple files then I need to call `loadItemForTypeIdentifier` within a for loop (for each image) but how can I do that if the `completeRequestReturningItems` method will be called after the first image/item?

Many Thanks
Paul

Comment: Hi Waggly, can you explain how you use uploadActivityRecord, I'm struggling with server upload because they dont allow me to use background thread with NSData upload.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I've subclassed NSOperation so that I have a download queue, and then used SOAP to upload the data to the server.  [link]http://sudzc.com/ is a useful service for creating your SOAP objects in objective-C.  Is the restriction to uploading to your server due to the size of your NSData?

Comment: Thanks @WagglyWonga for the reply, the restriction was on iOS side, not allowing me to upload in background thread or using any kind of blocks to check for completion. But I managed to upload it sending NSData directly using sendAsynchronousRequest with a Queue too. Just had to build the complete multipart request myself. It works :) Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem recently and was able to resolve it by adding a counter and counting down as the images successfully completed their block. Within the `loadItemForTypeIdentifier` completion block I then check to see if all items have been called before calling the `completeRequestReturningItems` within a `dispatch_once` block (just for safety's sake).

```
__block NSInteger imageCount;
static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

NSItemProvider *attachment = inputItem.attachments[0];

if ([attachment hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage])
{
 [attachment loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(NSData *item ,NSError *error)
 {
     if (item)
     {
         // do whatever you need to

         imageCount --;

         if(imageCount == 0){

             dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{

                 [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:nil];

             });
         }
     }
  }];
}
```

I can't say I feel like this is an overly elegant solution however, so if someone knows of a more appropriate way of handling this common use case I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Have you figured out how to extract the attributedContentText when using the extension from the Photo app?  It always seems to be blank but if the extension is used from Notes, the attributedContentText contains data.

Comment: @WagglyWonga I never needed to work with attributedContentText so I'm not sure, but the description in the apple documentation suggests it's an [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html) object, character data as well as style information. Are you sure photos and videos have this information associated with them?